# Performing sensitive Django actions while masking/hiding underlying URL

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django view that **confirms** the deletion of an instance. On this page is a simple form containing two buttons, "Cancel" and "Delete."

The *Cancel* button simply returns the user to the page from which the original delete button was pressed.

The *Delete* button jumps to a second view that performs the actual action. Thus, my URLs are defined as follows:

```
url(r'^confirmDeleteItem/(?P<item_key>\w+)$', 'confirm_delete_item'), # Confirms

url(r'^deleteItem/(?P<item_key>\w+)$', 'delete_item'), # Performs the action
```

On the confirmation page, the form is defined with a POST action that visits the second URL:

```
<form action="/squash/deleteItem/{{ item.key }}/" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

The problem I have with this is that the Items are fairly large (they store lots of data) and sensitive, so I'd like to force the user to jump through the confirmation hoop every time.

**I would like to either prevent the User from visiting the `/deleteItem/` page manually, or just hide the browser's loading of this page to avoid from it becoming stored in the history, accidentally bookmarked, etc.**

Is wrapping the action in an AJAX call the best way to solve this problem, or are there more standard/preferred solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting a session variable in confirmDeleteItem view (i.e. prepareToDelete = item.key) and checking in deleteItem view whether this session variable exists and whether the value match the item.key? Then you'd just need to remove it after actual delete occurred.

Comment: You could also set a datetime object to the session that would be the expiration time for the option to delete- so if they went to the delete URL after that time, they would get an error message.

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea which I'm not sure of, but should work in your case.

Check your referer in your `deleteItem` view. Like in [this snippet of code](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1474/). If user didn't come to the delete view from `confirmDelete` view, redirect him to the appropriate `confirmDelete` view.